# Remove git remote in IntelliJ/PyCharm

Tags: git, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I Git Remotes dialog I see this for my project:

[image]

How do I remove the second remote? The minus button is disabled.

This project is a symbolic link to another git project inside the main project's `misc/docker/...` directory.

The reason I want to remove this project because it complicates the git operations window.

Comment: From terminal? go to root directory of your repo, `git remote remove <remote-name> `

Comment: @brokenfoot That doesn't work since `git remote -v` shows only the root project's remotes. The problem is on IDE level.

Answer (score 2):

preferences > version control> click on remove icon. After that, the remote is going to appear in the "Unregistered roots" section and is not going to be available in the list of remotes to commit/push[image: version control]

Answer (score 0):

Try manually removing it through the **config file** in the **.git folder**. It should look something like,

```
[remote "Remote Name"]
    url = 
    fetch =
```

Comment: There is only root project's remote there. The problem is on my IDE's level.